# Upload File Website Hosted In IIS Returns HTTP 404 File Or Directory Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, upload, http-status-code-404

my site is hosted at IIS7.5
i have a controller action as below

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ClientDocument clientdocument,HttpPostedFileBase FilePath)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (FilePath != null && FilePath.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(FilePath.FileName);
                    string ext = filename.Split(char.Parse(".")).LastOrDefault();
                    clientdocument.FilePath = clientdocument.Title + "." + ext;
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), clientdocument.Title + "." + ext);
                    FilePath.SaveAs(path);
                    db.ClientDocuments.Add(clientdocument);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("../");
                }                    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return HttpNotFound("There Was A Problem Uploading File And Creating A Record");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "FullName", clientdocument.ClientID);
        return View(clientdocument);
    }
```

when i click the button it tries to upload the file but then show following error message

http 404 file or directory not found 
the resource you are looking for might have been removed,had its name changed or is temp unavailable

please assist how to configure iis7.5 to upload this file while in VS2010 every thing is working fine.

EDIT

After Changes @keshav Mentioned 
View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ClientDocument", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Attach New Client Document</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FilePath)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="file" id="FilePath" name="FilePath" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FilePath)
            </div>
   <fieldset>
}
```

and Controller:

```
[HttpPost,ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create(ClientDocument clientdocument,HttpPostedFileBase FilePath)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (FilePath != null && FilePath.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(FilePath.FileName);
                    string ext = filename.Split(char.Parse(".")).LastOrDefault();
                    clientdocument.FilePath = clientdocument.Title + "." + ext;
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), clientdocument.Title + "." + ext);
                    FilePath.SaveAs(path);
                    db.ClientDocuments.Add(clientdocument);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }                    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return HttpNotFound("There Was A Problem Uploading File And Creating A Record");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "FullName", clientdocument.ClientID);
        return View(clientdocument);
    }
```

still i am having same problem as before.

Comment: helpful tip: you can get path of a file with the following code:
extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

Comment: @Awan, I've moved your edit from wrong place (someones answer) to your question. Check if it should have been merged with your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you shouldn't have to change any settings in IIS...
further to what @Darin Dimitrov said about the exception can you change the code in the catch clause to:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
        ViewBag.errorMessage = ex.Message;
        return View("Error");
}
```

and in your error page (should have one under the shared view folder) add the following line

```
@ViewBag.errorMessage
```

I am thinking the code is throwing some exception on the server but not when you run it locally. This will help you narrow down problem. If you are still getting an 404 error then there probably is a setting issue.

Comment: **IIS_IUSRS need permission to read&write where file needs to be saved. if your website is running under DefaultApplicaionPool**

thanks ev1 & Keshav

Answer (score 2):

404 error means that you have attempted to request an url on the server that doesn't exist. You haven't shown how your view looks like but I suspect that you have some hardcoded url and you haven't used url helpers to generate the form. So here's the correct way to generate a form pointing to this controller action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Another issue is in your controller action. The following is wrong:

```
return RedirectToAction("../");
```

The RedirectToAction method expects an action name and not an url which is what you are providing. So make sure that you have passed an action name (and an optional controller name if the action is located on a different controller):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Also in your Create controller action if there's an exception inside the processing of the file upload you are returning `HttpNotFound` which results in a 404 error on the client. So make sure that this code doesn't throw an exception. You could log the error as well instead of simply redirecting in order to be able to determine what went wrong.

Comment: this is the view code. but the redirecttoaction("../"); is working fine on other pages.
`@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="stylized" class="myform">
        <fieldset>            `

Comment: I agree with RedirectToAction part. I would recommend changing it as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the / after Uploads

> var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"),
>   clientdocument.Title + "." + ext);

Comment: path.combile does that for us.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen after you publish the app ? If so the upload folder most likely didn't get copied over. Vs2010 doesn't publish custom folders unless you change the publish settings to include all files. Or you can go browse the site location and create the folder your self

**Edit**

I have a app with a similar set up and seem to be working fine. The Only difference I notice is in the html.begin. I explicitly specify the action and controller.

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Administrator", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "File upload was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" onclick="return confirm('Doing this will override any previous data. Are you sure you want to proceed?')"/>
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Upload")]
public ActionResult UploadPost()
{
  // my code
}
```

Try specifying your action and controller and see if that helps.

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to upload ?

Comment: after changes you mentioned again its working fine in VS2010 but in IIS 7.5 same problem.
maybe there is some settings need to be implemented on the Uploads directory in IIS, Any Idea?